# Simple CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() leads to IllegalMonitorStateException error

Tags: java, exception, monitor, completable-future

I'm trying this in java8:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
      () -> { return 911; });
    future.whenComplete(
      (result, error) -> {
        System.out.println("Alarm:" + result);
        error.printStackTrace();
      }
    );
    future.wait();
  }
```

Upon running, I got this output:

```
Alarm:911
[WARNING]
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:502)
    at mygroup.UseCompletableFuture.main (UseCompletableFuture.java:15)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Is the "error" information expected? Did I miss anything in my code snippet?

Comment: Object#wait method is from another universe (synchronized/wait/notify), I believe you need to use get() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception whose stack trace is shown is thrown by `future.wait()` and is not related to the `error` argument of the second `CompleableFuture`. It occurs because `wait()` requires the thread invoking it to be holding the object's monitor. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) for a description of what it means for a thread to be owner of the object's monitor. Your code basically has to be within a `synchronized` block in order to be able to call `wait()` or `notify()`. You probably intended to call `get()`, the `wait()/notify()` methods are generic synchronization methods inherited by `Object` and have been there since the beginning of Java.

As for the `error` parameter, it is indeed null, because the first stage completes normally. Hence, the line `error.printStackTrace()` should thrown a NPE. However, your code simply does not handle. It is thrown in the async thread that executes the stage, and remains silent. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183246/completablefuture-swallows-exceptions) in relation to this behavior.

I suspect you want to call the `get()` method on the future. First you should assign the second stage to a variable (`future` is still referencing the first stage):

```
future = future.whenComplete(
      (result, error) -> {
        System.out.println("Alarm:" + result);
        System.out.println(error);
        error.printStackTrace();
      }
);
```

Then you could call `get()` on it, which allows you to handle an `ExecutionException` which will wrap the NPE occurring in the second stage:

```
try {
    result = future.get();
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    ...
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `wait` method derives from the `Object` class. If you need to use it, you need to monitor the object.

In your case, you should not need to monitor, but you need to 'wait for the completable future to complete'. In this case you need to switch from `wait` to `get` method.

Comment: Or alternatively use `join()`.